# How to Determine Whose Turn it is in a Game of Tic Tac Toe in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on creating a Tic Tac Toe game in Visual Basic. I'm having lots of problems, but the one I'm focusing on right now is this:

There are 2 players, one human, and the other is the computer. What would be the simplest way to determine whose turn it is? I mean, clearly one player will be X and the other will be O, so I need to figure out how to determine whose turn it is so the program knows what letter to set as the text of the button.

Here is what I have for this portion of the code, but it's missing the part that would tell whether it places an X or an O since that's what my question is about.

```
    Public Class Form1

Private _currentPlayer As String = "O"
Private _gameArray As String
Dim turn As Integer = 1
Private _gameArray1 As Object

Private Property gameArray(p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer) As String
    Get
        Return _gameArray
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _gameArray = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Property gameArray(i As Integer) As Object
    Get
        Return _gameArray1
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        _gameArray1 = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe! Would you like to play a game?")
End Sub

Private Function nextPlayer() As String

    If _currentPlayer.Equals("O") Then
        _currentPlayer = "X"
        Return "O"
    Else
        _currentPlayer = "O"
        Return "X"
    End If

End Function

Private Sub printView()
    Console.WriteLine(btn1.Text & "|" & btn2.Text & "|" & btn3.Text)
    Console.WriteLine("----------------")
    Console.WriteLine(btn4.Text & "|" & btn5.Text & "|" & btn6.Text)
    Console.WriteLine("----------------")
    Console.WriteLine(btn7.Text & "|" & btn8.Text & "|" & btn9.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar)

    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "1"
            btn1.Text = "X"
        Case "2"
            btn2.Text = "X"
        Case "3"
            btn3.Text = "X"
        Case "4"
            btn4.Text = "X"
        Case "5"
            btn5.Text = "X"
        Case "6"
            btn6.Text = "X"
        Case "7"
            btn7.Text = "X"
        Case "8"
            btn8.Text = "X"
        Case "9"
            btn9.Text = "X"
    End Select
    printView()
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    If turn = 1 Or 3 Or 5 Or 7 Or 9 Then
        btn1.Text = "X"
        gameArray(0, 0) = "X"
        checkwin()
    ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn1.Text)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn1.Text = "O"
    End If
    turn += 1
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    If turn = 1 Or 3 Or 5 Or 7 Or 9 Then
        btn2.Text = "X"
        gameArray(0, 2) = "X"
        checkwin()
    ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn1.Text)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn2.Text = "O"
    End If
    turn += 1
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    If turn = 1 Or 3 Or 5 Or 7 Or 9 Then
        turn = 3
        btn3.Text = "X"
        gameArray(1, 0) = "X"
        checkwin()
    ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn1.Text)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn3.Text = "O"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn4.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn4.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(1, 0) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn5.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn5.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(1, 1) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn6.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn6.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(1, 2) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn7.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn7.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(2, 0) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn8.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn8.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(2, 1) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn9.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    Else
        btn9.Text = nextPlayer()
        gameArray(2, 2) = nextPlayer()
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub checkwin()

    If (btn1.Text = "X") And (btn2.Text = "X") And (btn3.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn4.Text = "X") And (btn5.Text = "X") And (btn6.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn7.Text = "X") And (btn8.Text = "X") And (btn9.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn1.Text = "X") And (btn4.Text = "X") And (btn7.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn2.Text = "X") And (btn5.Text = "X") And (btn8.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn3.Text = "X") And (btn6.Text = "X") And (btn9.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn1.Text = "X") And (btn5.Text = "X") And (btn9.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")
    If (btn3.Text = "X") And (btn5.Text = "X") And (btn7.Text = "X") Then MsgBox("X WINS!")

    If (btn1.Text = "O") And (btn2.Text = "O") And (btn3.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn4.Text = "O") And (btn5.Text = "O") And (btn6.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn7.Text = "O") And (btn8.Text = "O") And (btn9.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn1.Text = "O") And (btn4.Text = "O") And (btn7.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn2.Text = "O") And (btn5.Text = "O") And (btn8.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn3.Text = "O") And (btn6.Text = "O") And (btn9.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn1.Text = "O") And (btn5.Text = "O") And (btn9.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
    If (btn3.Text = "O") And (btn5.Text = "O") And (btn7.Text = "O") Then MsgBox("O WINS!")
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a private variable in the main class:

```
Private _currentPlayer as String = "O"
```

This sets the initial player as `O`

Then have a simple function that flips between `X` and `O` output:

```
Private Function nextPlayer() As String

    If _currentPlayer.Equals("O") Then
        _currentPlayer = "X"
        Return "O"
    Else
        _currentPlayer = "O"
        Return "X"
    End If

End Function
```

Then change your function to use this new helper:

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    If btn1.Text <> Nothing Then
        btn1.Text = nextPlayer()
         gameArray(0, 0) = nextPlayer()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("This position has already been taken, please select an empty square.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I implemented this, but now when I run the program, I get the "This position is already taken" message when I click on any of the buttons on the form, any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I take it each one of your board squares is a separate button?

Comment: Yes, I have 9 separate buttons.

Comment: OK, so you have 9 separate button handler functions also?

Comment: Ensure that they all have the correct `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3` etc through the entire handlers and perhaps change `If btn1.Text <> Nothing Then` to `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(btn1.Text) Then` ensuring you have the correct button numbers again in each handler.

Comment: Still getting the message no matter what button I click on. Do you think my array may not be empty and that's what's causing this?

Comment: As far as I can see in the code you've shared, this `MessageBox` only shows if there is something in the `btn1.Text` property, it makes no difference what is in the array. I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the `If btnTxt1.Text`... line in Visual Studio and seeing what the property is set to when the function runs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really new to this. How would I go about doing a breakpoint?

Comment: I can tell :) In Visual Studio you can right click on the line of code and look for `Set Breakpoint` in the menu - then when the code runs it will pause on this line - then you can hover over `btn1.Text` and see what it's value is...

Comment: It says btn1.Text is ""

Comment: Ugh, this program is due in 2 hours and so far all it does correclty is welcome the player.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don't think it's going to be possible to teach you how to write and debug code in 2hrs via SO comments - I think your best approach will be to submit your work as you have it, and then listen to the advice and critique from your tutor in order to get better :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to get all the points I can ha. Was really hoping to get this part figured out so I'd at least have something to work with. Thanks for trying :-)

Comment: I was finally able to solve the issue of the buttons saying they were already taken, but now I"m seeing that the program isn't actually taking turns, just simply placing an O in each button I press.

Comment: Set some breakpoints in the `nextPlayer()` function, try and figure out why it is always "O" by stepping through your code with F10 and seeing which paths it takes - make sure your Private variable isn't being reset each time you press a button

Comment: Stepping through the code it looks like for some reason nextPlayer() is never getting changed to X so remains at O.

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but what if instead of using the nextPlayer() method I declared a variable called "turn" and initialize it to "1". Then for each button click do something like "if turn = 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 Then btn1.Text = X Else If turn = 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 Then btn1.Text = O" Then have it add one to turn each time through?

Comment: That could work, as there are a finite number of turns

Comment: So far I haven't been able to get it to work. I'll update the code so you can see if you can spot what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the players in an array, and having a reference to the first player.

Sorry I can't remember VB syntax very well:

`Private _players As List Of Player`

When you initialise

`_players.Add(new HumanPlayer(...))`
`_players.Add(new ComputerPlayer(...))`

then store a reference to whichever one is currently playing, possibly with a `EndTurn()` function that advances the turn.

`Private currentPlayer as IPlayer = _players.First()`

Then a little function to advance it to the next player.

Apologies for my code being invalid VB I haven't done any VB for years.

This pattern makes your program a bit more flexible and easier to read, it also addresses the separation of concerns if you classes and interfaces correctly.